# elasticsearch group by inside group by

Tags: elasticsearch, group-by

I have a table which contains 2 IDs. The first one is userid and the second one dealid. I want to have a group by inside a group by. I tried doing this:

```
"query": {"match_all": {}},
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_userid": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "userid"
      }  
    },
    "aggs": {
      "group_by_dealid": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "dealid"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This doesn't work, because group_by_dealid isn't using group_by_userid. The output I need is that each user has a array of all the Deals he entered. The User can enter the same Deal multiple times.
Is there a way of doing this?